# Remove item from ArrayList issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a class that have a method of removing an object from other class. But it just worked inproperly, the output is not correct. Please help me through, and is there any better solution for this, I think my solution is quite cumbersome. Here is my code:

```
public List<Task> getTaskDue(){        
    List<Task> temp = this.taskCollection;
    for (int unit = 0; unit < this.unitCollection.size(); unit++){            
        for (int j = 0; j < this.unitCollection.get(unit).getAssessmentCollection().size(); j++){
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
                if (temp.get(i).getDueDate().compareTo(this.unitCollection.get(unit).getAssessmentCollection().get(j).getDueDate()) > 0)
                    temp.remove(i);
            }
        }  
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Updated: I have Diary class that has list of Task class and Assessment class that hold due date attribute. I want to create a method that return a new list which have a list of over due task by comparing the task from diary class with the due date attribute from assessment class. The program compile successfully but the result is not correct if I want to test the list return no task item since no task is over due.

Comment: Use an iterator when doing this.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect your code to do, and why the output you are getting is incorrect?

Comment: I have Diary class that has list of Task class and Assessment class that hold due date attribute. I want to create a method that return a new list which have a list of over due task by comparing the task from diary class with the due date attribute from assessment class. The program compile successfully but the result is not correct if I want to test the list return no task item since no task is over due.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like "removing" elements from the list isn't your ultimate problem.

You said you want your method to return a *new* list that contains elements from taskCollection based on some criteria. At the same time, I don't think you want to destroy or change taskCollection in any way.

So instead of creating temp as a reference to taskCollection, have it be a `new ArrayList<Task>()` instead. Then add tasks to temp (the new list) that you want to ultimately return from your method.

I am going to leave my adivce at that, because your code sample, in isolation, has a lot of unknowns that prohibit me from making any educated guesses on what you *really* need it to do.

Also, there are too many for loops! (I'm mostly kidding, but seriously...)

---

With more information from the comments below, I've modified your code to implement what I am suggesting. In order to add the items to temp (instead of remove them) I had to change your if statement from `> 0` to `<= 0`. Also, instead of iterating over taskCollection in the inner-most loop, you should get tha tasks from the current assessment and iterate over those.

```
public List<Task> getTaskDue(){     
    List<Task> temp = new ArrayList<Task>();

    for(int u = 0; u < unitCollection.size(); u++){
        Unit unit = unitCollection.get(u);

        for (int a = 0; a < unit.getAssessmentCollection().size(); a++){
            AssessmentItem assessment = unit.getAssessmentCollection().get(a);

            for (int t = 0; t < assessment.getTasks().size(); t++){
                Task task = assessment.getTasks().get(t);

                if (task.getDueDate().compareTo(assessment.getDueDate()) <= 0){ 
                    temp.add(task);
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }   
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I don't want to destroy the existing taskCollection, that's why I created a tempCollection which is a copy of all item in taskCollection. if each item in the tempCollection doesn't satisfy the condition, it will be removed from the list. If I have to deal with one list, its ok coz I will you iterator to solve the problem. I'm struggling with the unitCollection that have a list of Unit item, and each Unit item have a list of AssessmentItem. That why I only come up with this complicated method. Have u got any better sollution avoid using many for loop?

Comment: So taskCollection is a copy? If so, that isn't apparent in your code. You're just assigning temp to taskCollection with out copying it.

Comment: I tried to change like this: `List<Task> temp = new ArrayList<Task>(); 
        temp.addAll(this.taskCollection);` but the result is the same

Comment: That will at least preserve taskCollection. Now the "removing" is your real problem. However, I would personally create the list and only add the ones you want to return. What type of objects are in unitCollection?

Comment: I declared `List<Unit> unitCollection = new ArrayList<Unit>()`  The problem is I have to get getDueDate method of AssessmentItem which is a item of a Unit list.

Comment: I've just happen to code as exactly as what you mentioned above. The program return the result. But It seems that double up the list. tempCollection list now have dumplicate item, I think something wrong in the for loop, do you think so

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong in the loop. It display all overdue task. But it did twice. the result like this [item1,item2,item3,item3,item1,item2,item3], it should have looked like this [item1,item2,item3]

Comment: Exactly what you did above. is there any change that the loop is wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11174/discussion-between-jeremy-heiler-and-truong-thanh-dung)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to alter a list as you're iterating through it, use a ListIterator. Call [listIterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29) on your list to create one, then see relevant methods on ListIterator.

Comment: If I do like you, I might run into concurrentexception error >.<, so I chose to use traditional loop to get through list :(

Comment: Right, and doing it your way, you´re not running into problems, of course...?!?

Answer (score 0):

You are removing an object from an index but index in iteration is not altered. Due to the reason you would be skipping an element in the list. Perhaps that is the reason why your results are not correct.

Change:

```
if  ( temp.get( i ).getDueDate().compareTo( this.unitCollection.get( unit )
      .getAssessmentCollection().get( j ).getDueDate() ) > 0 )
    temp.remove(i);
```

to:

```
if  ( temp.get( i ).getDueDate().compareTo( this.unitCollection.get( unit )
      .getAssessmentCollection().get( j ).getDueDate() ) > 0 )
{  
    temp.remove(i);  
    i--;  
}
```

PS: Better always practice using flower braces irrespective of number of statements under the condition or loop.

Comment: Its not working >.<, the program compiled but no result returned.

Comment: @TruongThanhDung - *no result returned*. means? zero or some with as not expected? Show some of your input and expected to us and it would be possible to analyse.

Comment: means zero, no list displayed. I'm expecting all tasks from all unit will display because they're all overdue compared with the due date for assessment item :(